# missing orders after failed order

Tags: sales-order, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have noticed that after a customer does a purchase which fails on the Authorize.net side, the next successful transaction is not added.

Any idea why this may happen or how I can fix it?

Comment: If the order was not created then you should not have a successful transaction. But you should be able to see the transaction error in authorize logs

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. What I mean is that if the customer tries to order again with the same account and it is successful, then although the customer is charged and sees the success message on the magneto site, no successful order is visible from admin and no sales are made.